# Is there a specific word for "sheet music portfolio"?

Tags: single-word-requests, music

Is there a specific name for a portfolio (a type of briefcase) that is used exclusively for holding sheet music?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As it stands this question is incomplete. Please edit to provide context (explain why this question comes up) and to show results of research attempted before asking. Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about a physical folder or a collection of your work?

Comment: @JamesJiao question needs to be answered to better understand your question, then I would ask if the "sheet music portfolio" is in contrast to another type of music portfolio.

Comment: Is there a specific name for a portfolio of *drawings, photographs,  etc.?* I think probably the short answer in every case is *"No"*.

Comment: I know what the OP means. It **is** a type of briefcase used by music teachers and the like, but I know of no specific name for it. I haven't seen one for a very long time, but I do remember that they had a metal bar of some kind to secure them shut.

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge. I've had several conductors, all of which referred to them differently—the most common being *folder*.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean these, leather bags with a simple bar closure:

[image: traditional leather music case from the Cambridge Satchel Company]

If so I think they are simply called music bags or music cases.

Comment: (N.B. The one pictured is from [The Cambridge Satchel Company](https://www.cambridgesatchel.co.uk/buy/the-music-bag/))